# Replace Multiple "-" PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Preg-Replace more than one underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729500/php-preg-replace-more-than-one-underscore)

Hi, I'm just wondering how I can replace 2 or more - signs in a string with just one in PHP.

So like

1-2---3--4

would go to

1-2-3-4

Thanks :)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729500/php-preg-replace-more-than-one-underscore

Answer (score 5):

Use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace):

```
$str = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $str);
```

Comment: or better `$str = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $str);`

Comment: @Reveren Wouldn't that miss the --- in the middle of the string?

Comment: Well, technically that would recude the number of replacements but IMHO the difference is negligible and `/-+/` is a lot cleaner :)

Comment: @Neil Aitken, no, `{2,}` means 'at least two characters'.

Answer (score 0):

No need regex

```
$text="1-2---3--4";
$s = implode("-",array_filter ( explode("-",$text) )) ;
print_r($s);
```

Comment: Exploding to array then joining back to string is neither more clear nor effective than the RegEx version.

Comment: if that's what you think. But not me.