# preg_replace that only removes more than 2 lines

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to use preg_replace command **that only removes more than 2 lines**. But my code removes all the lines. I'm using:

```
$content = preg_replace("/\r\n/", "\n", $_POST['content']);
```

Input:

```
Line1
Line2

Line3



Line4
```

Output:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
```

I want:

```
Line1
Line2

Line3

Line4
```

So the code must remove only the extra lines in the text. I can use different types of codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6360566/367456

Comment: Thanks to last pattern in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68873784/367456 now a complete dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```php
echo preg_replace('/(\R)(\R){2,}/', "$1$2", $str);
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/tcNiQx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Replace three or more of one with two of it:

```
... = preg_replace('/((\R)\2)\2+/', '\1', ...);
```

Where

- `\R` is what constitutes a line (newline)
- `(\R)` is the sub-pattern of *one*
- `((\R)\2)` is the sub-pattern of *two of one* via a back-reference and captures the replacement
- `\2+` is one or more of *one* via a back-reference

This makes three or more of *one* to replace with two of *one*.

Compare with: Replace two ore more of one with one of it as it is a little simpler ([and exists for reference already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729500/367456)):

```
... = preg_replace('/(\R)\1+/', '\1', ...);
```

And specifically in context of your question:

Replace two line-breaks that are followed by one or more line-break/s with those first two as any of the line-breaks may be different:

```
... = preg_replace('/(\R\R)\R+/', '\1', ...);
```

---

Rationale:

> But my code removes all the lines.
>
> `... = preg_replace("/\r\n/", "\n", ...);`

Yes it may appear so, but it actually replaces every [Carriage-Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) + [Line-Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (CRLF; `\r\n`) with a Newline (LF; `\n`).

So it removes all the Carriage-Return-s (CR; `\r`) and keeps the Line-Feed-s (LF; `\n`).

That only for a better understanding in context of your question. The important learning is that you definitely do not want to replace with the string `"\n"` as it - how you write - *"removes all the lines"*.

The resolution to this then is the educated guess that you want to replace with `"\r\n"` as you reference those in your pattern.

The rest is similar to this question:

- [PHP Preg-Replace more than one underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729500/367456)

which suggests a pattern like this:

```
... = preg_replace('/__+/', '_', ...);
# or:
... = preg_replace('/(_)\1+/', '\1', ...);
```

but is about replacing two or more. You would like to replace three or more with two consecutive to stay.

With the earlier assumption to replace with `"\r\n"` (CRLF) this would be to replace three or more of them with two of them:

```
... = preg_replace('/\r\n\r\n(\r\n)+/', "\r\n\r\n", ...);
# or:
... = preg_replace('/(\r\n)\1\1+/', '\1\1', ...);
```

As in your variation what constitutes a new line consists of two characters (the CR and the LF), the "character" to replace is in fact a [sub-pattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) (constituted by the parenthesis).

Extending the last example with back-references to align it more to the *to or more* case from the references question:

```
 ... = preg_replace('/(\r\n)\1\1+/', '\1\1', ...);
```

And then creating another back-reference to replace with as you want to replace three or more with two:

```
 ... = preg_replace('/((\r\n)\2)\2+/', '\1', ...);
```

Now coming back to the beginning where it remained unclear what actually constitutes a new line in your subject there still is left the chance that not "`\r\n`"  but also other variations (e.g. each single "`\r`" or "`\n`") may so. As dealing with lines is common with regular expressions there luckily is a dedicated [escape-sequence](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/regexp.reference.escape.php) for all this:

```
\R

line break: matches \n, \r and \r\n
```

(this description is a summary)

Using `\R` instead of `(\r\n)` makes the pattern:

```
 ... = preg_replace('/(\R{2})\R+/', '\1', ...);
 # or:
 ... = preg_replace('/((\R)\2)\2+/', '\1', ...);
```